# PHP PDO. Не понимаю в чём ошибка. Приведите пожалуйста рабочий пример использования

Tags: php, pdo

Есть самописный движок достаточно простой CMS. Есть задача переписать запросы с mysql на PDO. Разбираюсь как им пользоваться. Библиотека PDO на CentOs стоит(php-pdo). Не понимаю где проблема.
Приведите пожалуйста простой пример использования начиная от создания объекта PDO(присвоения его переменной) до простого SELECT запроса к базе данных и выводом данных к примеру по var_dump.
P.S. вопрос может и глупый, просто я завис, с 10 часов утра уже сижу с вопросом.

Comment: А документации не хватает? Там полно примеров начиная подключением и выборкой и кончая межзвёздными полётами

Comment: Про межзвёздные полёты не видел, может кините ссылку?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Вот с утра сидел, а задал вопрос и сам же нашёл ответ. Помогло надо же. Оказывается я fetch не у того объекта вызывал.

```
$pdo = new PDO(("mysql:host=" . $mysqlhost . ";dbname=" . $mysqldb),$mysqluser,$mysqlpassword,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
$pdo->exec("SET NAMES UTF-8");
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF-8");
$query = "SELECT $row FROM `$table`";
$toExecuteAr = array();
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($result->execute($toExecuteAr) !== false) {
  while ($resultRow = $result->fetch()) {
    var_dump($resultRow);
  }
}
```

Comment: Это всё очень плохо. [как соединяться](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). [Как делать запрос](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select). Никакое $row и $table **никогда** нельзя в запрос передавать. Писать надо запрос РУКАМИ, без переменных.

Comment: Руками не получится, так как row меняется в зависимости от данных которые выводятся. Не вижу смысла выгружать из БД лишние данные. А вот то что убрать названия из переменных в массив $toExecuteAr - такое как вариант можно сделать.

Comment: один мальчик экономил на спичках. потому что считал себя очень умным. не знал как пользоваться стандартными библиотеками, но все равно считал. в итоге ничего не с экономил но получил SQL инъекцию

Comment: Мне не зашла история из Вашей жизни. Толку Вам писать про себя, что Вы там какой то умный.